# Platform browser dynamic providers not used

Tags: javascript, angular, locale

I'm trying to set my LOCALE_ID token before my angular app bootstraps by using the documentation method:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' }]
});
```

When checking the token in my AppModule's constructor, it seems like it's been reset to defaults

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {
        console.log('Locale - App module', this.locale);
    }
}
```

Outputs: `Locale - App module en-US`

What am I missing here ?

Here is a Stackblitz reproducing the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rdtb6

Comment: If your `AppModule` imports another module that provides this token, then it will overwrite the providers from bootstrapping.

Comment: It's the first time we're introducing the token in the project, so it shouldn't be the cause

Comment: You're going to have to create a reproducible example with stackblitz, because all you've provided is the documentation example. Which is assumed to work, and if it doesn't then you should open a bug report. Otherwise, I don't see how people can answer this.

Comment: Edited the question with a stackblitz example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be passing providers to platform injector not to compiler injector:

```
platformBrowserDynamic([ {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' }])
                                          \/
                                    extraProviders
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Beware that to test it in stackblitz you have to reload application since Angular creates platform only once.

See also:

- [What you always wanted to know about Angular Dependency Injection tree](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-dependency-injection-and-tree-shakeable-tokens-4588a8f70d5d)

Comment: this is similar to `providedIn: platform`?

Answer (score -1):

You can try just set the provider in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
       // your objects here
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: That way is working indeed ! I need to get the locale info from my API though, I was planning on using a fetch in the main.ts for that